# Python Click multiple group names

Tags: python, command-line-interface, alias, python-click

Is it possible to do something like this with Python Click?  I want to use different names for the same `click.Group`.

```
import click

class CustomMultiGroup(click.Group):

    def group(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Behaves the same as `click.Group.group()` except if passed
        a list of names, all after the first will be aliases for the first.
        """
        def decorator(f):
            if isinstance(args[0], list):
                _args = [args[0][0]] + list(args[1:])
                for alias in args[0][1:]:
                    cmd = super(CustomMultiCommand, self).group(
                        alias, *args[1:], **kwargs)(f)
                    cmd.short_help = "Alias for '{}'".format(_args[0])
            else:
                _args = args
            cmd = super(CustomMultiCommand, self).group(
                *_args, **kwargs)(f)
            return cmd

        return decorator

@click.group(cls=CustomMultiGroup)
def mycli():
    pass

@cli.group(['my-group', 'my-grp'])
def my_group():
    pass

@my_group.command()
def my_command():
    pass
```

I want my command lines to be something like:

```
mycli my-group my-command
```

and

```
mycli my-grp my-command
```

but reference the same function.

This post is a reference to [Python Click multiple command names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641928/python-click-multiple-command-names)

Comment: Click has the concept of alises?

Comment: Take a look at [Command Aliases](http://click.pocoo.org/5/advanced/)

Comment: It's more something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641928/python-click-multiple-command-names

Comment: The group itself is not addressed from the command  line.  You would generally only address a group if it was itself inside of a group.  So for your first line to be useful it would need to be a member of another group.  So it would not be `@click.group()` it would need to be `@my_outer_group.group()`, where `my_outer_group` was a previously declared group.  Can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: It's not the case but it can be. I'll test it soon

Comment: Stephen Rauch i've edited my message with my test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click.Group` and `click.Command` behave differently so you need to modify the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641928/python-click-multiple-command-names) to allow the aliasing group to access the aliased group's commands:

#### Custom Class

This class overides the `click.Group.group()` method which is used to decorate group functions. It adds the ability to pass a list of group aliases. This class also adds a short help which references the aliased group.

```
import click

class CustomMultiGroup(click.Group):

    def group(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Behaves the same as `click.Group.group()` except if passed
        a list of names, all after the first will be aliases for the first.
        """
        def decorator(f):
            aliased_group = []
            if isinstance(args[0], list):
                # we have a list so create group aliases
                _args = [args[0][0]] + list(args[1:])
                for alias in args[0][1:]:
                    grp = super(CustomMultiGroup, self).group(
                        alias, *args[1:], **kwargs)(f)
                    grp.short_help = "Alias for '{}'".format(_args[0])
                    aliased_group.append(grp)
            else:
                _args = args

            # create the main group
            grp = super(CustomMultiGroup, self).group(*_args, **kwargs)(f)

            # for all of the aliased groups, share the main group commands
            for aliased in aliased_group:
                aliased.commands = grp.commands

            return grp

        return decorator
```

#### Test Code:

```
@click.group(cls=CustomMultiGroup)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group(['my-group', 'my-grp'])
def my_group():
    """ My Sub Command """
    pass

@my_group.command('my-command')
def my_command():
    click.echo("My Command")

cli('--help'.split())
cli('my-grp --help'.split())
cli('my-group --help'.split())
cli('my-grp my-command'.split())
cli('my-group my-command'.split())
```

#### Test Results:

```
Usage: my_cli [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  my-group  My Sub Command
  my-grp    Alias for 'my-group'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to have command aliases in Click is using one of the following packages:

- [click-aliases](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-aliases)
- [Cloup](https://cloup.readthedocs.io/en/stable), which also adds several other features other than [aliases](https://cloup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/aliases.html).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Cloup.

The two implementations are slightly different.

- Cloup stores aliases of a command in the command itself. This allows Cloup to document aliases of a command (also) in the `--help` of the command itself.
- click-aliases always shows aliases of (sub)commands in the "Commands" section of a group. In Cloup, you can enable/disable this behavior according to your preference (by default, aliases are not shown).